# Troubles with installation of Homebrew

Tags: terminal, homebrew, osx-yosemite, failed-installation

I am trying to install Homebrew on a fresh install of OS X Yosemite (removed old partition using disk utility and did a complete re-install, carried over no media, completed about 10 minutes ago).

Unfortunately I have closed terminal since the first time I attempted the install using:

"ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)",

as such I do not have the original error code. I used the install command as provided above, and was directed to install command line tools. This part played out fine. After command line tools installed I hit 'return' as directed, and it began 'installing home-brew'. **The installation seemed to stall and then an error message was displayed.**

So then I re-attempted the install by simply re running the same terminal prompt and terminal gave me this message:

"Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.",

**then this it said that the installation was successful.** *However*, I was then prompted to run brew doctor, to which I then ran and subsequently was alerted with:

"Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.

Error: Failure while executing: /usr/bin/otool -L /usr/bin/install_name_tool".

I then used the prompt "brew help" to see if it would work and it did, but again trying to use brew doctor yielded: "Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.

Error: Failure while executing: /usr/bin/otool -L /usr/bin/install_name_tool".

I then attempted to use the lines from https://gist.github.com/mxcl/1173223 to uninstall Homebrew. Terminal displayed a message of success. I then quit terminal, re-opened it and typed brew to which I was given a catalogue of options to which I assumed brew was not installed as I had thought.

So, I do not know what went wrong with my installation of Homebrew and if someone could educate me that would help. I would also appreciate information of how to go about uninstalling and then reinstalling Homebrew with success.

Thanks

Answer (score 18):

I just came across same problem (using Yosemite), with same error message. I'm a newbie on this, so I might be doing, but what I tried seemed to be working. I think this is not an installation error, but we just have to agree the license and run via sudo.

Here are the step I took. (It's a bit redundant)

First I did "sudo brew doctor"

Then it said:

> You have not agreed to the Xcode license agreements, please run
> 'xcodebuild -license' (for user-level acceptance) or 'sudo xcodebuild
> -license' (for system-wide acceptance) from within a Terminal window to review and agree to the Xcode license agreements.
>
> Error: Failure while executing: /usr/bin/otool -L /usr/bin/install_name_tool

So I did "xcodebuild -license"

Then it said:

> Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please
> re-run as root via sudo.

So I did "sudo xcodebuild -license"

Then it said:

> You have not agreed to the Xcode license agreements. You must agree to
> both license agreements below in order to use Xcode. Hit the Enter key
> to view the license agreements at
> '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/License.rtf'

And then I hit enter and the MAC SDK AND XCODE AGREEMENT.
You have to read to the end to actually agree to this. So I kept hitting space to show the entire Agreenent.
At the end, it said

> By typing 'agree' you are agreeing to the terms of the software
> license agreements. Type 'print' to print them or anything else to
> cancel, [agree, print, cancel]

Then I typed "agree" and "brew doctor," it said

> Your system is ready to brew.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

open you xcode tools ,and it will pop up a window to let you agree xcode license and back to term window ,it will work

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's ridiculously effective and I should have thought to do this after upgrading the software. Thanks!

Comment: I think both answers would work. My installation was asking for me to xcode app and agree, but command line instructions from @Keico also worked for me.